# Фильтр плохих слов на python

Tags: python

Я сделал "фильтр плохих слов", но не могу сделать 1 вещь. Например, если в тексте есть бл# и сабля, то код заменит бл# на #%#, а сабля на са#%#. Честно, я уже сломал голову и не знаю как это исправить. (Наверняка есть решение с индексами, но у меня не получилось). Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
import random

chars = ["*","#","%","&","?","@"]
bw  = ["fuck", "bitch"]
txt = 'Fuck you  fucker bitch'.lower().split(' ')

for word in txt:
    if word in bw:
        temp = random.sample(chars, len(word))
        i = ''.join(temp)
        txt = [x.replace(word, i) for x in txt]

res = ' '.join(txt)
print(res)
```

- Вход: Fuck you fucker bitch
- Вывод: @&?* you  @&?*er ?%@&*

Answer (score 3):

Специально для решения таких задач существуют регулярные выражения. Разумеется, любой фильтр можно обойти, поэтому как именно вы составите регулярку, определяется только вашей фантазией.

Например, в интернете я нашёл вот такое прекрасное регулярное выражение, которое не только решает вашу задачу, но и находит многие другие нецензурные слова:

```
(\s+|^)[пПnрРp]?[3ЗзВBвПnпрРpPАaAаОoO0о]?[сСcCиИuUОoO0оАaAаыЫуУyтТT]?[Ппn][иИuUeEеЕ][зЗ3][ДдDd]\w*[\?\,\.\;\-]*|(\s+|^)[рРpPпПn]?[рРpPоОoO0аАaAзЗ3]?[оОoO0иИuUаАaAcCсСзЗ3тТTуУy]?[XxХх][уУy][йЙеЕeEeяЯ9юЮ]\w*[\?\,\.\;\-]*|(\s+|^)[бпПnБ6][лЛ][яЯ9]([дтДТDT]\w*)?[\?\,\.\;\-]*|(\s+|^)(([зЗоОoO03]?[аАaAтТT]?[ъЪ]?)|(\w+[оОOo0еЕeE]))?[еЕeEиИuUёЁ][бБ6пП]([аАaAиИuUуУy]\w*)?[\?\,\.\;\-]*
```

Вот конкретно для слова "Бля":

```
(\s+|^)([бБ6][лЛ][яЯ9])
```

`(\s+|^)` - здесь мы смотрим, чтобы сначала было либо начало строки `^`, либо один или более символ пробела `\s+`.
`([бБ6][лЛ][яЯ9])` - тут мы определяем слово, подразумевая, что оно состоит из трёх букв. Для каждой буквы в квадратных скобках мы задаём диапазон возможных значений. Таким образом следующие слова тоже попадут под фильтр:

```
6ля (цифра 6 вместо буквы)
бЛя
бл9
```